# anyone can give the solution

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service, data-service

Failed to save lightningDataServices.cmp: No INTERFACE named markup://flexipage:availableForAllPages foundNo INTERFACE named markup://flexipage:availableForAllPages found: Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes/documentation). It always helps to look at the documentation when you get errors like this.